# Display single latest instagram photo on your website

Tags: php, embed, instagram

I am looking all over the web and can't believe I can't find an answer to my question.
I would like to display the latest **single** instagram photo on my website. simple as that.

No gallery, no fancybox, no slideshow etc etc

I found this useful link:
http://www.blueprintinteractive.com/blog/how-instagram-api-fancybox-simplified

it's actually working but it doesn't give an option of how many images you would like to display
and I would like only one latest instagram image.

anyone have an idea?

Thanks

Comment: have you looked at the source code they give you ?

Comment: I recommend the [Instagram Basic Display API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `break` `foreach` after showing first image like below:

```
foreach ($result->data as $post) {
  // Do something with this data.
  break; // for one result only
}
```

Or add `&count=1` at end of `url` as below

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/ID-GOES-HERE/media/recent/?access_token=TOKEN-GOES-HERE&count=1
```

Comment: Hi @Manoj Yadav  anyway I can also display the title of that latest photo?

Comment: You can use caption `$post->caption->text` but caption may not be available all the time, so you have to do something like this `echo isset($post->caption) && isset($post->caption->text) ? $post->caption->text : '';`

Comment: Great. any link I can get more properties from? maybe date, comments etc etc? thanks a lot

Comment: You can `var_dump($post);` or `print_r($post);` to view more properties

Comment: Update: "The Instagram Legacy API is deprecated," ([Platform Changelog, June 29 2020](https://www.instagram.com/developer/changelog/)).

Answer (score 1):

The answer is right here: http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_media_recent_with_client_id

Count option for number of media !

Comment: I see "sorry, this page isn't available," likely because "the Instagram Legacy API is deprecated," ([Platform Changelog, June 29 2020](https://www.instagram.com/developer/changelog/)).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$page_id = 'YOUR ID';
$access_token = 'YOUR ACCESS TOKEN';
$json_object = @file_get_contents('https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/' . $page_id . 
'/media/recent/?access_token=' . $access_token . '&count=1');
$indata = json_decode($json_object);
echo $indata->data[0]->images->low_resolution->url // for low res
echo $indata->data[0]->images->thumbnail->url;      //for thumbnail
echo $indata->data[0]->images->standard_resolution->url; //for standard res
echo $indata->data[0]->caption->text; //for caption
```

Embedding the whole post may be a solution:

```
$json_post = @file_get_contents('https://api.instagram.com/oembed/?url=' . $indata->data[0]->link);
$oembed = json_decode($json_post, true);
echo $oembed['html'];
```

Good luck!

Comment: Update: "The Instagram Legacy API is deprecated," ([Platform Changelog, June 29 2020](https://www.instagram.com/developer/changelog/)).